# Get x-axis label data onClick function in react chartjs2 for line chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

OnClick of x-axis label I have to get the clicked label value and call api based on the x-axis label in react chartjs-2 line chart.
I have already tried with getElementAtEvent (function) but could not able to get the clicked x-axis label.

How to get this x-axis label value in line chart.Also I have to add underline for each x-axis label.

How to achieve both of this functionalities.

Any thoughts?